# Problems with separator of thousands in DataFrame loaded from Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

i'm loading a DataFrame from excel with this structure:

[Excel structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJBRN.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wRtH75zU5GrXKnLG5Zc67HhszBSHj-i3/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=105770797963127682400&rtpof=true&sd=true

The code is the following:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.set_page_config(page_title='Censo Bovino - Datos',
                page_icon=':ox:',
                layout='wide')

st.sidebar.header("Demo Datos")

st.sidebar.markdown('---')

st.title('Datos')

st.markdown('---')

@st.cache_data
def load_data():
    df= pd.read_excel(
        io='CENSOS-BOVINOS-2023-Final.xlsx',
        engine='openpyxl',
        sheet_name='BOVINOS Y PREDIOS',
        skiprows=4,
        usecols='A:Q',
        nrows=1121,
        thousands='.'
        )

    return df
    
df = load_data()

st.dataframe(df.style.format(thousands='.'))
```

The code for the plot is:

```
columnas = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['DEPARTAMENTO', 'MUNICIPIO']]

variables = st.sidebar.selectbox('Selecc',
                                 columnas)

variables2 = st.sidebar.selectbox('Selecc',
                                 columnas)


Grafico1 = go.FigureWidget()
Grafico1.add_scatter(x=df['DEPARTAMENTO'].unique(),
                     y=df[variables].unique(),
                     name=variables,
                     mode='lines+markers'
                     )
Grafico1.add_bar(x=df['DEPARTAMENTO'].unique(),
                 y=df[variables2].unique(),
                 name=variables2,
                 )

Grafico1.update_layout(
    title=f'{variables} vs. {variables2}',
    margin=dict(
        l=10,
        r=10,
        b=10,
        t=40,
        pad=5
    ),
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)'
)

st.plotly_chart(Grafico1, use_container_width=True)
```

[Streamlit plot looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpKQo.png)
[Streamlit plot looks]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsNT9.png

As you can see, Streamlit change the "." by "," so when I plot, the legends look like this: "Total = 2,403173" instead of looking like this "Total = 2.403.173.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try `st.dataframe(df.style.format(thousands=".", subset=["TOTAL BOVINOS"]))` ? And if you need to target all the numeric columns, remove the `subset` parameter in the [`Styler.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Timeless . It works for the ```st.dataframe```. But not for the plot. I added the code for the plot to the post.

Comment: In your new code, you don't show how you define `variables` and `variables2`. I got a `NameError`.

Comment: Sorry and thanks again, @Timeless , I updated the code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the issue like this:

```
@st.cache_data
def load_data():
    df=pd.read_excel(
        io='CENSOS-BOVINOS-2023-Final.xlsx',
        engine='openpyxl',
        sheet_name='BOVINOS Y PREDIOS',
        skiprows=4,
        usecols='A:Q',
        nrows=1121,
    )

    return df

df = load_data()

#this line shows the data frame in a correct form
st.dataframe(df.style.format(thousands='.'))
```

The code for the plot:

```
with open ('Colombia.geo.json') as response:
    Departamentos = json.load(response)

locs = df['DEPARTAMENTO']

for Departamento in Departamentos['features']:
    Departamento['id'] = Departamento['properties']['NOMBRE_DPT']
mapa = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(
                    geojson=Departamentos,
                    locations=locs,
                    z=df[variables],
                    colorscale='prgn_r',
                    colorbar_title=f'{variables}to.',
                    #this line fixes the legends in the plot
                    hovertemplate='%{z:.4s} <extra>%{location}</extra>',
                    ))
mapa.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                        mapbox_zoom=4.3,
                        height=700,
                        margin=dict(
                            l=10,
                            r=10,
                            b=10,
                            t=10,
                            pad=5
                            ),
                        
                        paper_bgcolor='rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)',
                        mapbox_center = {"lat": 4.570868, "lon": -74.2973328})

st.plotly_chart(mapa, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]